# Чтение файлов из asset Android

Tags: android, java, файлы

В простом Java приложении все просто. Используется BufferReader.

```
try {           
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
        while ((word = in.readLine()) != null) {
            dictionary.put(word, 0);
        }
        in.close();            
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();           
    }
```

И тогда все строки файла записаны в HashMap, с которым дальше работаем.

Но как сделать так, что бы Android увидел этот файл. Файл лежит в папке asset. Как бы логично что:

```
try {
        AssetManager assetManager;          
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(assetManager.open("dictionary.txt"));
        while ((word = in.readLine()) != null) {
            dictionary.put(word, 0);
        }
        in.close();
        //assetManager.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();           
    }
```

Но нет, ошибка. Как достать этот файл?

**UPD *SOLVED***
Метод:

```
public static void loadDictionary (Context context) throws IOException {    
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("dictionary.txt"));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(istream);

            while ((word = in.readLine()) != null) {
                dictionary.put(word, 0);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // FileNotFoundExpeption       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // IOExeption
        }       
}
```

Вызов:

```
try {
    Spell.loadDictionary(getBaseContext());
} catch (IOException e) {
    //IOExpeptino
}
```

Спасибо user - **afiki**

Comment: какая ошибка?

Comment: выдало что не обьявлен InputStream.

Поправил на
AssetManager assetManager;
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("dictionary.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

Ошиька - The constructor BufferReader(InputStream) is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
```

а ты пытаешься вызвать метод у null.

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("dictionary.txt"));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(istream);

    while ((word = in.readLine()) != null) {
        dictionary.put(word, 0);
    }

    in.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();           
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, оно начало что-то делать, но this.getAssets() я не могу использовать, этот метод статический. Он в класе с логикой, а не в Activity. Аргументом метода я поставил 

public static void loadDictionary (Context context) throws IOException {
// method body
}

Но что именно надо было бы взять за аргумент при его вызове?
Logic.loadDictionary(???);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android